# What does this HTTP response status code mean?

Tags: ruby, http, rest, mongrel

For a RESTful API I am building, I'm getting the following response code in the Ruby server log: `HTTP/1.1" 200 203`

I know 200 means OK, but then whats the 203 for? Surely there can only be one status code?

The full responses are:

```
"GET /getLocationForAllFriends?uid=4&passport=0000 HTTP/1.1" 200 203 0.4243
"GET /getLocationForAllFriends?uid=5&passport=0000 HTTP/1.1" 200 8 0.3206
```

Everything makes sense except for the "slot" where 203 an 8 are.

BTW, the server is Mongrel

Comment: it seems like number of bytes returned to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 203 is the length in bytes of the returned data, it is not a response code.

The response in the first line was 203 bytes and took 0.4 seconds to serve, and the second was 8 bytes and took 0.3 seconds. Both were `GET` requests and the response code was in both cases `200`.

Answer (score 1):

203 is the length of the response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just one question, why is it 8 for `{"s":0}`, and 12 for `{"s":222}`? I.e. always one more than the number of characters in the response?

Comment: Probably a newline character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

203 means `Non-Authoritative Information` (or, "The server successfully processed the request, but is returning information that may be from another source").

But, I would bet that it's not really an HTTP status code you're looking at, especially since you get an 8 in another of your cases. Take a look in the server config file to see what it is that it's actually logging.

**Edit:** Judging from the other answers, it's probably the length of the response (in bytes).